# How to clone or copy a list in kotlin

Tags: list, copy, kotlin

How to copy list in Kotlin?

I'm using

```
val selectedSeries = mutableListOf<String>()
selectedSeries.addAll(series)
```

Is there a easier way?

Comment: I think your solution is already the easiest way, in case you don't need deep cloning.

Comment: Copying a list just copies references to items. Items themselves won't clone. Don't forget to clone items during copying lists if you wish to have deep cloned lists.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

This works fine.

```
val selectedSeries = series.toMutableList()
```

Comment: `val selectedSeries = series.toList()` also works because it calls `toMutableList()` in its implementation.

Comment: @FlávioFaria just tested it with `===` and have to say `toList()` doesn't copy the collection, but `toMutableList()` does

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy It *does* copy, except in the case of empty lists. If the source is empty, `Iterable.toList()` returns`emptyList()`, which always returns the same (immutable) object. So if you test with `emptyList()` you'll get the same object back.

Comment: this is not a good answer, and definitely not the right one, there is no guarantee that future implementations might change, unless its specifically documented that this method call will always return a new copy.

Comment: @BrunoJCM, that's not the case anymore. The Kotlin docs state that `toMutableList()` returns a *new* list, "Returns a new MutableList filled with all elements of this collection.".

Comment: @PärNilsAmsen Verified what you stated is valid! Once contents changed, the two mutablelist will have a different hash. https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjAiLCJwbGF0Zm9ybSI6ImphdmEiLCJhcmdzIjoiIiwianNDb2RlIjoiIiwibm9uZU1hcmtlcnMiOnRydWUsInRoZW1lIjoiaWRlYSIsImNvZGUiOiIvKipcbiAqIFlvdSBjYW4gZWRpdCwgcnVuLCBhbmQgc2hhcmUgdGhpcyBjb2RlLiBcbiAqIHBsYXkua290bGlubGFuZy5vcmcgXG4gKi9cblxuZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFsIGEgPSBtdXRhYmxlTGlzdE9mPEludD4oMSlcbiAgICB2YWwgYiA9IGEudG9NdXRhYmxlTGlzdCgpXG4gICAgYS5hZGQoMilcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKGEuaGFzaENvZGUoKSlcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKGIuaGFzaENvZGUoKSlcbn0ifQ==

Comment: This help also when you face the problem of overwriting some data class (List) item, just before to reassign the list make sure you're assigning a MutableList.

Comment: It’s still the least intuitive way ever if you want an _immutable_ snapshot of a _mutable_ collection to call something like `.toMutable…` on it.

Answer (score 55):

You can use

**List  -> toList()**

**Array -> toArray()**

**ArrayList  -> toArray()**

**MutableList  -> toMutableList()**

---

**Example:**

```
val array = arrayListOf("1", "2", "3", "4")

val arrayCopy = array.toArray() // copy array to other array

Log.i("---> array " ,  array?.count().toString())
Log.i("---> arrayCopy " ,  arrayCopy?.count().toString())

array.removeAt(0) // remove first item in array 

Log.i("---> array after remove" ,  array?.count().toString())
Log.i("---> arrayCopy after remove" ,  arrayCopy?.count().toString())
```

**print log:**

```
array: 4
arrayCopy: 4
array after remove: 3
arrayCopy after remove: 4
```

Comment: You're confusing Array with ArrayList. They're two very different things. In your code `array` is actually an `ArrayList` while `arrayCopy` is an `Array`. Their names are misleading.

Answer (score 50):

If your list is holding [kotlin data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), you can do this

```
selectedSeries = ArrayList(series.map { it.copy() })
```

Comment: what if you want to copy only 1 attribute of the arraylist to another arraylist?

Comment: best response. Thx. All the others not working

Comment: If you want a `mutableList`, you can use `selectedSeries = series.map { it.copy() }.toMutableList()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the right answer when working with lists of custom models or data class.

Comment: this is the best answer for me since we're using delegate adapter recyclerView

Comment: This gives me some ideas to deal with my case, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I can come up with two alternative ways:

```
1. val selectedSeries = mutableListOf<String>().apply { addAll(series) }

2. val selectedSeries = mutableListOf(*series.toTypedArray())
```

Update: with the new Type Inference engine(opt-in in Kotlin 1.3), We can omit the generic type parameter in 1st example and have this:

```
1. val selectedSeries = mutableListOf().apply { addAll(series) }
```

FYI.The way to opt-in new Inference is `kotlinc -Xnew-inference ./SourceCode.kt` for command line, or `kotlin { experimental { newInference 'enable'}` for Gradle. For more info about the new Type Inference, check this video: [KotlinConf 2018 - New Type Inference and Related Language Features by Svetlana Isakova](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyljSWm0Y_k), especially 'inference for builders' at 30'

Comment: should be splitted into 2 answers imho, since I think the first one is correct, but the latter lacks some beauty.

Comment: @Jacob Wu: I was surprised to see that the * symbol in the second solution did not produce an error. What does it do? I did a search with "unary multiplication" but didn't find anything.

Comment: @Lensflare * means to destruct an array into separate items, e.g. mutableListOf( * [1, 2, 3] ) means mutableListOf(1, 2, 3), it's like the opposite operation to vararg

Comment: @Jacob Wu: Thank you. With your answer, I was able to find out that the operator is called "spread operator". I see how it helps by combining some parameters with an array into a varargs list. But what benefit does it have in your example? Is it faster or something? Or is it the key to ensure that the collection is copied?

Comment: @Lensflare I think the benefit is just the syntax - the code is short, and no explicit generic type is required(like in my 1st example). Behind the scene, I believe the code is compiled to array operations, so performance should be the same.

Comment: it's inefficient. The same as Java's `List.addAll` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54381327/difference-between-arraylist-addalllist-and-new-arraylistlist-for-content Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/46846074/4548520 Test it https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/pllbim18v1vfa6one4i8l0hasj/497pnhfpsmvb73sn2378cv692d

Comment: Be careful about copying lists of non-primitive objects this way. The new list will contain the same objects as the old list, so changing an item in one will affect it in both lists. A true deep copy will also copy the list items. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51480079/1015595.

Answer (score 21):

Just like in Java:

List:

```
    val list = mutableListOf("a", "b", "c")
    val list2 = ArrayList(list)
```

Map:

```
    val map = mutableMapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2, "c" to 3)
    val map2 = HashMap(map)
```

Assuming you're targeting the JVM (or Android); I'm not sure it works for other targets, as it relies on the copy constructors of ArrayList and HashMap.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the provided extension `Iterable.toMutableList()` which will provide you with a new list. Unfortunately, as its signature and [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html) suggest, it's meant to ensure that an `Iterable` is a `List` (just like `toString` and many other `to<type>` methods). Nothing guarantees you that it's going to be a **new** list. For instance, adding the following line at the beginning of the extension: `if (this is List) return this` is a legitimate performance improvement (if it indeed improves the performance).

Also, because of its name, the resulting code isn't very clear.

I prefer to add my own extension to be sure of the result and create a much more clear code (just like we have for [arrays](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/copy-of.html)):

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.copyOf(): List<T> {
    return mutableListOf<T>().also { it.addAll(this) }
}

fun <T> List<T>.mutableCopyOf(): MutableList<T> {
    return mutableListOf<T>().also { it.addAll(this) }
}
```

Note that `addAll` is the fastest way to copy because it uses the native `System.arraycopy` in the implementation of `ArrayList`.

Also, beware that this will only give you a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

EDIT:

You might want to use the more generic version:

```kotlin
fun <T> Collection<T>.copyOf(): Collection<T> {
    return mutableListOf<T>().also { it.addAll(this) }
}

fun <T> Collection<T>.mutableCopyOf(): MutableCollection<T> {
    return mutableListOf<T>().also { it.addAll(this) }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Shouldn't it be `addAll(this@copyOf)`, because `this` inside `apply` will refer to the newly created empty list? Either that or `mutableListOf<T>().also { it.addAll(this) }`?

Answer (score 9):

For a shallow copy, I suggest

```
.map{it}
```

That will work for many collection types.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work for `Map`s. It compiles, but since the `it` is a `Map.Entry`, and the copy is shallow, you have the same entries.

Comment: @noamtm yes, that is what I mean with shallow copy. This method will never copy the entries. It will only make a copy of the collection with the same entries. Map is nothing special here.

Comment: My point is, that even though it's tempting to use it on maps too, and it compiles and seems to work - it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `ArrayList` constructor: `ArrayList(list)`

Answer (score 5):

```
var oldList: List<ClassA>?
val newList = oldList.map { it.copy() }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [the `toCollection()` extension method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-collection.html):

```
val original = listOf("A", "B", "C")
val copy = original.toCollection(mutableListOf())
```

This will create a new `MutableList` and then add each element of the original to the newly-created list.

The inferred type here will be `MutableList<String>`. If you don't want to expose the mutability of this new list, you can declare the type explicitly as an immutable list:

```
val copy: List<String> = original.toCollection(mutableListOf())
```

Answer (score 3):

```kotlin
val selectedSeries = listOf(*series.toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the best and most idomatic way is use collection builders in new versions of Kotlin (1.6+)

```kotlin
   val shallowListCopy = buildList { addAll(list) }
```

Comment: Why did you call it a ```shallow``` copy? Overview of the function and test of its behaviour shows it returns a ```deep``` copy -- not ```shallow```.

Comment: @Gleichmut I meant it form point of view on items... surely the list is a different instance, but it still referencing elements of the original list.

Comment: you are right, it is indeed a ```shallow``` copy. I wrote a test suite to confirm its behaviour. From your perspective what would you suggest as a ```deep``` copy in the modern ```kotlin```?

Comment: The best and simplest way is to have models as a structure of data classes, and you can copy them without additional cost, like maintain your own copy methods.

Comment: `listOf(instances).map{ it.copy() }`

Comment: Thanks, I came to this idea too, but I also got information in case you will have ```Collection``` as a member field of your ```data class```, ```.copy()``` call would not make a ```deep``` copy of this collection. Haven't verified it yet.

Answer (score 1):

After trying shallow copy, deep copy cloning and many more i found this solution surely it will work for you.

```
val iterator: Iterator<Object> = yourList.iterator()
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        newList.add(iterator.next().copy())
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple lists has many right solutions above.

However, it's just for shallows lists.

The below function works for any 2 dimensional `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` is, in practice, equivalent to `MutableList`. Interestingly it doesn't work when using explicit `MutableList` type. If one needs more dimensions, it's necessary make more functions.

```
fun <T>cloneMatrix(v:ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>):ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>{
  var MatrResult = ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>()
  for (i in v.indices) MatrResult.add(v[i].clone() as ArrayList<T>)
  return MatrResult
}
```

Demo for integer Matrix:

```
var mat = arrayListOf(arrayListOf<Int>(1,2),arrayListOf<Int>(3,12))
var mat2 = ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>>()
mat2 = cloneMatrix<Int>(mat)
mat2[1][1]=5
println(mat[1][1])
```

it shows `12`

Answer (score -6):

Try below code for copying list in **Kotlin**

```
arrayList2.addAll(arrayList1.filterNotNull())
```

Comment: This doesn't copy a list, it just adds a list to an exiting list (so the result would be ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>).