# Difference between ArrayList.addAll(list) and new ArrayList<>(list) for content copying

Tags: java

I know that `list2.addAll(list1)` allows us to append additional objects to `list2` from `list1` if `list2` already had some objects before calling this method

But I don't append anything and I want to know the difference of the next case

Would be there any difference when making a copy of a list using next methods

For example I have a list of some objects (`list1`) and I want to make a copy of it, copy its content to another list (to a new list - `list2`)

```
List<Foo> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(new Foo());
...
```

Method 1

```
List<Foo> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

Method 2

```
List<Foo> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.addAll(list1);
```

**Update**

Actually even IntelliJ IDEA suggests me to convert method 2 to method 1:

[image]

Comment: `addAll` also does some size checks (whether to enlarge the underlying array etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think **method 2 would be a little inefficien**t and my point of view is:

When you do this:

```
List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>(list1);
```

**ArrayList already knows the size it needs to allocate to the memory** that is a count of the Object in list1.

While in method 2 it creates a **list2 object with default size**. At it updates itself when you perform an add operation. As it will be an **extra operation.**