# Why add method overwrites all items in array list

Tags: kotlin

I have board for game tic-tac-toe. When I'm tryna add new board to list of boards it's always overwrites

```
fun String.replaceUnusualSymbols() =
    replace(", ", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

fun Array<Array<Char>>.printBoard(board: Array<Array<Char>>) = indices.forEach {
    println("|${board[it].contentToString().replaceUnusualSymbols()}|")
}

fun main() {
    var board = Array(3) { Array(3) { ' ' } }
    val game: ArrayList<Array<Array<Char>>> = arrayListOf()
    board[0][0] = 'X'
    game.add(board) // add first board
    board[1][1] = 'X'
    game.add(board) // add second board
    println(game.size)
    game.forEach {
        it.printBoard(board) // but outputs always second board
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the exact output that you get?

Comment: @dunni `2
|X  |
| X |
|   |
|X  |
| X |
|   |`

Comment: The program did what was designed ;) - you added the same board twice.

Comment: @Vicctor, but firstly I added board with only one symbol X it'll be 0 index and after I added second board with two symbols X. When I print game board I should get 2 different boards

Comment: Nono... you added X at position 0,0 then to exactly same board added X at position 1,1 - board. Please read about Koltin object references for better understanding. You simply added to the list game reference to the same object twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. `Array` is a [mutable collection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html#collection-types). Since you only created one `var board`, there's only once instance - which is mutated every time you do `board[0][0] = 'X'` or `board[0][1] = '0'`.
2. `it.printBoard(board)` isn't printing each board, it's only printing the same `board`.

#### Copying the mutable Array

You can try [copying the board](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46846025/4161471) every time you want to add the current board state to `game`.

Note that because `board` is a nested array, just doing `board.copyOf()` isn't enough - this won't copy recursively. So we have to specifically copy each row of `board` as well.

Because `map {}` returns a `List` and `board` is an `Array`, we have to convert the copied result using `toTypedArray()`.

```kotlin
  board[0][0] = 'X'
  game.add(board.map { row -> row.copyOf() }.toTypedArray()) // add first board

  board[1][1] = '0'
  game.add(board.map { row -> row.copyOf() }.toTypedArray()) // add second board
```

What we end up with is something that's pretty clunky and verbose. We can try making an extension function for the copy, but then we'll still have the risk involved with mutable collections. What happens if at some point you forget to copy the board?

To keep this answer short and focused, I'll leave refactoring to use immutable collections as an exercise for the reader, with some hints:

- How can you use a `class` to encapsulate the game logic?
- Instead of using a `List<List<Char>>`, can you create a `data class`?
- Can you create a function that both 1. adds a new symbol to the board, and 2. saves the current game state, in one go?

#### `printBoard()`

`printBoard()` is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) has both a receiver and an argument of type `Array<Array<Char>>`, which is unusual.

```kotlin
//      receiver
//         ↓
fun Array<Array<Char>>.printBoard(board: Array<Array<Char>>) 
//                                          ↑     
//                                       argument
```

This is causing one bug. When you call `it.printBoard(board)`, it will use the indices of `it`, but it will print the values of `board`.

```kotlin
//                                        the indices come from the receiver
//                                                                ↓
fun Array<Array<Char>>.printBoard(board: Array<Array<Char>>) = indices.forEach {
    println("|${board[it].contentToString().replaceUnusualSymbols()}|")
} //              ↑
//   the values come from the argument
```

So when you use it in a loop like this

```kotlin
game.forEach {
//              argument
//                  ↓
    it.printBoard(board)
//  ↑     
// receiver
}
```

it won't print each board.

Here's a fixed version that will only print the receiver.

```kotlin
fun Array<Array<Char>>.printBoard() = indices.forEach {
  println("|${this[it].contentToString().replaceUnusualSymbols()}|")
}
```

##### Replace `replaceUnusualSymbols()` with `joinToString()`

And I'll go one step further - we can get rid of `contentToString()` and `replaceUnusualSymbols()` and use the Kotlin stdlib function [`joinToString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html):

```
fun Array<Array<Char>>.printBoard() {
  val boardString = joinToString(
    separator = "\n",
    prefix = "\n",
  ) { row ->
    row.joinToString(" ", prefix = "|", postfix = "|")
  }

  println(boardString)
}
```